# Is it possible to break out of a loop in twig?

Tags: templating, forloop

Is it possible to break out of a loop in twig? If it is, how would I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Marion Newlevant wrote a Craft plugin that adds `{% break %}` and `{% continue %}` tags to Twig:

https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-mnbreakandcontinue

The Craft 3 version is [Twig Perversion](https://plugins.craftcms.com/twig-perversion)

Comment: @nicael certainly not, your answer is definitely the best way to do it without any plugins.

Answer (score 16):

Currently there is no special build-in command to do it (unless you want to use a plugin, as [stated](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/864/250) by Brandon Kelly). There is a workaround, however. The workaround is to check for additional condition.

```
{% set break = 0 %}

{# this variable we will set to 1 when we do not want code in our loop to run anymore #}

{% for i in 20..100 if break == 0 %} 
    ...
    {# on some condition we will set break to 1 to prevent running of further code #}
    {% set break = 1 %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Interesting. Apparently [you can use Twig conditional filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672796/how-can-i-use-break-or-continue-within-for-in-twig-template) as well. Have you run into a practical need for this, or is this a theoretical question?

Comment: @Matt Didn't know about conditional filters.  About practical need - yes, finding if number is prime ;-) And nobody forbid you to post an answer about using filters to break from a loop (I won't edit mine because its *your* idea) :-)

Comment: For reference, it doesn't look like break or continue will ever be part of Twig: https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/654

Comment: @Brad So exclude "currently"?

Comment: @nicael - It's still technically accurate. There's always the chance it being missing will annoy us enough that we'll add it in Craft, like we did with {% switch %}.