# How to check if number is prime?

Tags: templating, variable, number

How do I check if a given number is prime in twig?

Comment: I'm curious about the use case you want to implement this, nicael.

Comment: @Christian Well... I'll think :D

Answer (score 2):

Example using build-in functions (sure, not the best ;-) ).

Supposing that `number` is our number:

```
{% set result = 0 %}
{% if number / number|round == 1 %}
    {% set result = 1 %}
    {% if number > 3 %}
        {% for i in 2..number-1 if result == 1 %}
            {% if number is divisibleby(i) %}
                {% set result = 2 %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Now, `result` equals to:

- `0`, if `number` is not integer
- `1`, if `number` is prime
- `2`, if `number` is composite

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number

Comment: Also: `if result == 1` in line 4 makes no sense

Comment: @Christian I have already read about prime number (what am I missing?). And line 4 is valid. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry nicael, I overlooked that you are overwriting the result var if your number is a composite. Only read this: `{% if number / number|round == 1 %}{% set result = 1 %}` and immediately the word integer came to mind.

Comment: @Christian Yes, it does )) So what? Some simpler check which I don't know about?

Comment: All good, nicael! I only thought "huh these are integers and not primes" and posted my dumb comment. Sorry again!

Answer (score 1):

I think the question of the use-case is vital here. If you want to check whether a large number is prime or not, you will need a plugin and a lot of math.

If your number is guaranteed not too big, I would use twig's [in](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator) operator:

```
{% set primes = [2, 3, 5, 6, 11, 13, 17, 19] %}
{% if n > primes|last %}
  too big to tell
{% elseif n in primes %}
  {{n}} is prime
{% else %}
  {{n}} is composite
{% endif %}
```

Or check for prime factors in a loop:

```
{% set primes = [2, 3, 5, 6, 11, 13, 17, 19] %}
{% if n > (primes|last) * (primes|last) %}
  too big to tell
{% else %}
  {% set isComposite = false %}
  {% for p in primes %}
    {% if (not isComposite) and  (n is divisibleby (p)) %}
      {{n}} is composite (divisible by {{p}})
      {% set isComposite = true %}
      {# optional break #}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% if not isComposite %}
    {{n}} is prime
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

([Twig doesn't have a native break tag, but you can use a plugin](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/862/is-it-possible-to-break-out-of-a-loop-in-twig))